# What's an elegant way to extract a series of entries in a list of tuples into sublists?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Say I have a series of entries in a list of tuples like this:

```
TRUE = 1
listOfTuples = [('selectable', 'frequency'), ('color', 'green'), ('item', '10 Hz'), 
                ('value', 10), ('align', 'left'), ('hidden', TRUE), ('item', '20 Hz'), 
                ('value', 20), ('align', 'right'), ('item', '50 Hz'), ('value', 50), 
                ('item', '100 Hz'), ('value', 100), ('textColor', 0xFF0000)]
```

Now I want to extract a list with individual item entries like this:

```
[(('item', '10 Hz'), ('value', 10), ('align', 'left'), ('hidden', TRUE)),
 (('item', '20 Hz'), ('value', 20), ('align', 'right')),
 (('item', '50 Hz'), ('value', 50)), 
 (('item', '100 Hz'), ('value', 100), ('textColor', '0xFF0000'))]
```

The delimiting keyword to identify a sublist is always `item` or the end of the list. There can be an arbitrary number of tuples between two adjacent delimiters. The content of the list before the first occurrence of `item` is to be ignored. The detection of the keyword `item` should be case insensitive.

I am not a Python afficionado, so I don't know how to apply something like list comprehension (if that's actually possible), given that I need to extract lists between delimiters. Of course I can do it the pedestrian way by traversing through the list, identifying the positions of the keyword in the tuples and then extracting the sublists but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Please show what you’ve tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tuple()` function to transform lists into tuples, so you will be able to append all of the tuples inside `listOfTuples` variable into the output that you need:

```
TRUE = 1
lot = [('selectable', 'frequency'), ('color', 'green'), ('item', '10 Hz'), 
                ('value', 10), ('align', 'left'), ('hidden', TRUE), ('item', '20 Hz'), 
                ('value', 20), ('align', 'right'), ('item', '50 Hz'), ('value', 50), 
                ('item', '100 Hz'), ('value', 100), ('textColor', 0xFF0000)]

l = [[]]
for i in lot:
    if i[0]=='item':
        l[-1] = tuple(l[-1])
        l.append([])
    l[-1].append(i)
print(l[1:])
```

Output:

```
[(('item', '10 Hz'), ('value', 10), ('align', 'left'), ('hidden', 1)), (('item', '20 Hz'), ('value', 20), ('align', 'right')), (('item', '50 Hz'), ('value', 50)), [('item', '100 Hz'), ('value', 100), ('textColor', 16711680)]]
```

The only disadvantage of this method is that you need to remove the first element of the output list of tuples, so it may doesn't work in certain situations.

Comment: Thanks to @Andrej Kesely and Cardstdani for your solutions. I must admit, Andrej's solution goes well beyond my rudimentary understanding of Python. Cardstdani's solution is easier for me to comprehend. I need more time to absorb the individual bits and pieces of Andrej's solution and will vote for Cardstdani's for now as it is based on Python's intrinsic capabilities without the need for importing. I voted both up.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for the task:

```py
from itertools import accumulate, groupby

TRUE = 1
listOfTuples = [
    ("selectable", "frequency"),
    ("color", "green"),
    ("item", "10 Hz"),
    ("value", 10),
    ("align", "left"),
    ("hidden", TRUE),
    ("item", "20 Hz"),
    ("value", 20),
    ("align", "right"),
    ("item", "50 Hz"),
    ("value", 50),
    ("item", "100 Hz"),
    ("value", 100),
    ("textColor", 0xFF0000),
]


a = accumulate(t == "item" for t, *_ in listOfTuples)

out = []
for _, g in groupby(zip(a, listOfTuples), lambda k: k[0]):
    l = tuple(t for _, t in g)
    if l[0][0] == "item":
        out.append(l)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    (("item", "10 Hz"), ("value", 10), ("align", "left"), ("hidden", 1)),
    (("item", "20 Hz"), ("value", 20), ("align", "right")),
    (("item", "50 Hz"), ("value", 50)),
    (("item", "100 Hz"), ("value", 100), ("textColor", 16711680)),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so in the meantime I learned more about list comprehension, the use of `_`, `*` and more than one index in a for loop. Besides, a good friend came up with the following solution:

```
indices = [i for i, value in enumerate(listOfTuples) 
           if value[0].casefold() == "item"] + [len(listOfTuples)]
out = [listOfTuples[i:j] for i,j in zip(indices[:-1], indices[1:])]
```

`Indices` contains all occurrences of `item` and the index of the last item in the list. Using `indices` in a shifted fashion  (`zip(indices[:-1], indices[1:])`) allows then the straightforward construction of `out`.

Answer (score 0):

A constructive approach with no conditionals. Use `itertools.groupby` to group per `'item'`. Grouping is a True/False classification process (*ideally gives raise to an alternate sequence of True/False values!*), so you can slice by block of 2 and chain them together.

The split-right (*initial*) condition means that the 1st group with `item` is found on the "right" and what is on the "left" can be forgotten (`[1:]`-part).

```
import itertools as it

listOfTuples = # see question

# group by item & discard 1st group due to split-right condition
lst = tuple(tuple(grps) for _, grps in it.groupby(listOfTuples, lambda p: p[0] == 'item'))[1:]

# chain the slices
lst_new = [tuple(it.chain.from_iterable(lst[2*i:2*(i+1)])) for i in range(len(lst)//2)]

print(lst_new)
```

Same idea but with generators

```
...

lst = (tuple(grps) for _, grps in it.groupby(listOfTuples, lambda p: p[0] == 'item'))
next(l) # split-right initial condition
l1, l2 = it.tee(lst)
n = len(tuple(l2))

lst_new = [tuple(it.chain.from_iterable(it.islice(l1, 0, 2, None))) for _ in range(n//2)]
```

A (*logical different*) index based approach

```
...
# indices of the items
iter_ = filter(None, (tuple(grps)[0][0] if check else None for check, grps in it.groupby(enumerate(listOfTuples), lambda p: p[1][0] == 'item')))
# zip-stuffs
it1, it2 = it.tee(iter_)
next(it2)
it2 = it.chain(it2, iter((len(listOfTuples),)))
# apply the slices and cast to tuples
lst_new = list(map(tuple, map(listOfTuples.__getitem__, it.starmap(slice, zip(it1, it2)))))

print(lst_new)
```